# In Java SE: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have these two entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STAT_SETS")
public class StatisticSet extends ClientServerSharedObject {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="statSet")
    @MapKey(name = "name")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<AbilityName, Ability> abilities = new EnumMap<>(AbilityName.class);

    public StatisticSet(Race race) {
        for (AbilityName abilityName : AbilityName.values()) {
            abilities.put(abilityName, new Ability(abilityName, getModifier()));
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ABILITIES")
public class Ability extends ClientServerSharedObject {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STAT_SET_ID", nullable = false)
    private StatisticSet statSet;
}
```

I'm trying to persist an instance of `StatisticSet`, and I get this error:

`org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : org.package.Ability.statSet`

Right now I'm using Hibernate with Apache Derby in Java SE, with RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions. This worked fine when I was using it in a Java EE container with JTA. Hibernate knew to create the link back from `Ability` when it was added to the list in `StatisticSet`.

Why does this happen? Does it have anything to do with the lack of JTA? The `persist()` is happening between the `begin()` and `commit()` of an EntityTransaction. Can I fix it, or will I always have to set the link manually in both directions in java SE with something like this:

```
abilities.put(abilityName, newAbility);
newAbility.setStatSet(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before saving `Abitlity` safe `statSet` that ability has first.

Comment: Isn't the CascadeType.ALL supposed to handle it, so that I don't have to save every property manually?

Comment: Check first, ask questions later.